Ubuntu login page freezes
When I boot up my laptop with Ubuntu Studio 22.04, the login page sometimes freezes up and won't allow me to enter my password. The solution is to shut down and reboot. It then works. About 70% of the time the computer starts normally, but about 30% of the time I get this annoying freezing when I can't enter the password. I've put up with this for months, but now I'd like to fix it permanently if possible.

What display manager is currently selected at your login screen, Wayland or Xorg?

I don't know. How can I check?

Use this command echo "$XDG_SESSION_TYPE" and add the output to your question using edit

Ok, thanks. It said X11

So can you tell me what now? Now that you know it is X11
